# run action after an event is completed in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Action1
triggers Event1
Event2
in this order.

Action2 also triggers Event2.

I need to execute a method after Event1 is triggered AND COMPLETED.

How would I achieve this in C#/.NET?

The key is that I need to execute that method when the event is completed, because only then I have access to certain properties of an object.

I was thinking of adding a variable globally at class level and assign it a value inside Event1 handler.
Then checking inside Event2 handler if the variable was initialised, which means we are at a stage where Event1 was completed. And then inside Event2 handler adding my method.

This doesn't seem to work because Event2 is triggerred extremely often when Action2 is executed (an action I don't care about) and I get a stack overflow error message.
Is there a good way to actually make this work?

Can(how) I do something like override the library and add a new event (that does nothing) triggered when an existing event is completed; then I would use the new event just to attach a handler to it and put my method there.

These events and actions are inherent to a framework so I don't have much control over them as their definition is hidden inside .net libraries.
So I'm interested in some general principles and tricks and these are the limitations/setbacks.

Some sample code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969955/how-to-use-invoke-to-call-a-method-after-an-event-was-finished

Comment: Why not just add it to the Event1 invoker?

Comment: If your edit was intended to address my answer, I have no idea what you are talking about, *the event handlers have finished executing after `Invoke` returns*

Comment: Sorry Bradley, I hadn't seen your answer yet. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Btw where would I invoke it? Since I need this method each time an event of type event1 is triggered, would I create a handler for event1 like ...Instance.Move += new PageEventHandler(myHandler) and then do Move.Invoke inside myHandler?

Comment: @ringosstaro - Just an another handler to the event - handlers run one after another so the second handler will just run when the first handler is done.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Alternatively, make sure all your event invocations go through the same method and then use the approach in my answer.

Comment: It won't be inside the handler `Event1?.Invoke` is how you "call" the event in a threadsafe way from the owning class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handling is by its nature synchronous (assuming somebody doesn't use `async void` or start their own thread in a handler) so the following code:

```
Event1?.Invoke();
//Do stuff after Event1
```

Will already do what you are asking. If you need to wait for some asynchronous task that is kicked off by a *handler* of `Event1` then you will need to do that apart from the event invocation process.

Comment: How do I do it apart from the event invocation process?

Comment: @AndrewPaes That depends on your application. Events shouldn't return a value, so you would have no inherent way to track when the event handler asynchronous operation finished. I would suggest some sort of `TaskCompletionSource`.